# Thread no actualiza su propertyValue

Tags: java, hilos, javafx, multitasking

Estoy trabajando en un programa para ver las etapas de ordenamiento de un arreglo con hilos de ejecución, mediante una interfaz gráfica. Bueno el problema se presenta con un thread cuando intento actualizar su value Property, en este caso trabajo con arreglos, para actualizar la interfaz gráfica, específicamente un textArea.
El codigo que tengo en la clase task es el siguiente:

```
@Override 
public int [] call (){
    bubbleSort ();
    return null;
}
```

Despues agregaria mas algoritmos de ordenamiento en el call, el metodo bubbleSort lo tengo asi

```
public void bubbleSort (){
    try {

    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i --){
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j ++){
            if (array [j] > array [j+1]){
                int tempo = array [j];
                array[j] = array [j + 1];
                array [j+1] = tempo;
                Thread.sleep(30);
                showChanges();

            }

        }

    }


    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex){
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
    }

}
```

Entonces cada vez que el algoritmo hace un cambio en el arreglo, llamo al metodo showChanges para que actualize el textArea de la interfaz. Adjunto el metodo showChanges ();

```
 public void showChanges (){

           Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                      @Override public void run() {
                          updateValue(array);
                      }
                  });
                //mostrarArray();   }
}
```

Se supone que deberia actualizar el textArea que se encuentra en la clase fxmlController, pero solo muestra un arreglo.

```
s1.valueProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> { 
                   if (newValue != null){
                   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i ++){
                        tx1.appendText(String.valueOf(newValue[i]));

                    }   
                    }


            });
```

Aclaro que el s1 es el task y tx1 el textArea. Agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Lo has probado poniendo el **sleep** después del ``showChanfes(()``

Comment: Gracias por responder ! Si, de hecho quité el sleep, pero sigue igual. Ahora estoy mas confundido, ya que antes el thread enviaba casi el mismo array a la interfaz gráfica, pero ahora me fije mejor y envía el array ordenado, es decir, el final. Pero yo quiero los pasos intermedios :(

Comment: Con todos estos trozos a medias de código es imposible lograr darte una respuesta de que debería modificar para lograr lo que buscas te invito a leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y según el caso un ejemplo mínimo ejecutable, porque tampoco somo adivinos de código, imagina que tu teniendo el código no sabes que hacer y nosotros con trozos de código menos. Aun así, te he dejare un ejemplo de cómo deberías de implementar una solución simple utilizando el patrón observador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso vamos a crear una clase `BubbleSort` que implementara ´Runnable´ para ejecutarse en un hilo independiente, agregaremos la interfaz ´ SortActionListener ´ al constructor que se encargará de registrar los eventos tanto de ejecución como de finalización según el patrón de diseño observador, esto nos servirá en JavaFx para ir actualizando el estado del array con cada movimiento que se aplique el array. Para nuevos procesos de ordenamiento se seguirán los mismos pasos:

1. Crear la clase con un nombre descriptivo `BubbleSort`.
2. Implementar de la interfaz `Runnable`.
3. Utilizar `listener.onActionListener(String);` para pasar el valor del array
   luego de cada cambio.
4. Utilizar `listener.onFinish();` cunado se haya finalizado la ejecución.
5. Crear un nuevo método similar a `startBubbleSortThread` y cambiar la implementación de `BubbleSort` a la nueva y sus respectivas variables.

   ```
   public interface SortActionListener {
     void onActionListener(String value);
     void onFinish();
   }
   ```

---

```
    public class BubbleSort implements Runnable {

    private final SortActionListener listener;
    private final Integer[] array;
    private final long delay;

    public BubbleSort(Integer[] array,long delay, SortActionListener listener){
        this.array = array;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {

            for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i --){
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j ++){
                    if (array [j] > array [j+1]){
                        int tempo = array [j];
                        array[j] = array [j + 1];
                        array [j+1] = tempo;
                        Thread.sleep(delay);
                        // Notificamos que hubo un cambio en el arreglo, enviando
                        // el String del arreglo despues del moviemiento.
                        listener.onActionListener(Arrays.toString(array));
                    }
                }
            }
            // Notificamos que el proceso ha finalizado 
            listener.onFinish();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex){
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            listener.onFinish();
        }
      }
    }
```

---

```
   public class OrdenamientoPatronObservador extends Application {

    public static final long DELAY_TIME = 1000;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Creamos grid para poder ubicar los compnentes.
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(12);

        // Variable donde se actualizará el estado del ordenamiento en burbuja
        Text lbBubble = new Text("");

        Button btnStart = new Button();
        btnStart.setText("Iniciar");
        // Agregamos el manejo de evento clic para inciar el ordenamiento
        btnStart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // Array para pruebas, si hay mas procesos seria uno por proceso.
                Integer[] array = {3, 7, 1, 3, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6};

                // Iniciamos el método startBubbleSortThread que iniciara el  
                // hilo de ejecución y actualizara el texto de forma dinámica.
                // Para agregar más procesos solo debes replicar este método  
                // con los nuevos ordenamientos y su Text correspondiente.
                startBubbleSortThread(array, DELAY_TIME, lbBubble);
            }
        });

        // Agregamos el boton y lbBubble en las posiciones del grid.
        // Agregar más componentes Text segun cada proceso de ordenamiento nuevo.
        grid.add(btnStart, 0, 0);
        grid.add(new Label("Burbuja"), 0, 1);
        grid.add(lbBubble, 1, 1);

        // Código para agregar el grid a la escena
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(grid);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Ordenamiento en Tiempo Real!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param a         Arreglo para ordenamiento
     * @param delay     Tiempo de retraso entre acción del ordenamiento
     * @param text      Varible a actualizar en escena por cada acción
     */
    public static void startBubbleSortThread(Integer[] array,long delay, Text text){
        // Iniciamos un hilo independiente para el proceso de ordenamiento
        // y Creamos la clase BubbleSort con el array he implementamos la interfaz
        // SortActionListener encargada de observar los cambios del proceso,
        // implementando asi el patron de observador.
         Thread thBubble = new Thread(new BubbleSort(array, delay, new SortActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onActionListener(String value) {
                                // Cada vez que cambie el valor lo reciviremos aqui
                                // y actualizaremos la interfaz con Platform.runLater
                                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        text.setText(value);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {                                
                                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        text.setText(text.getText() + " - FINALIZADO");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }));

                thBubble.setDaemon(true);
                thBubble.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    }
```

Si quieres ejecutar el código puedes descargarlo desde mi página de github: https://github.com/remorandev-Never-Stop-Learning/OrdenamientoPatronObservador